# Language in the output of a shell script is changing

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote a script that lists all the packages installed on a machine, and then compares it with another list located in `/tmp/pacotes_iniciais.log`. For some reason, the language of the output changes sometimes. It alternates between English and Portuguese.

The first time I run the script, it outputs `Mon` (Monday), but in the second run the date is `Seg`, which is the diminutive for *Segunda* (Monday in Portuguese).

Also, when in English, the words are getting cutted at the 14º character.

This is problematic because totaly unvalidates the comparison.

Below is an excerpt of the script that creates the list and performs the comparison:

```
dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' >> /tmp/lista_pacotes.log

echo "\nPackages added until" $(date) "\n" >> /tmp/diferencas.log

grep -F -x -v -f /tmp/pacotes_iniciais.log /tmp/lista_pacotes.log >> /tmp/diferencas.log
```

**The content of `/tmp/diferencas.log`**

Second run:

```
Packages added until Seg Nov 14 08:48:22 BRT 2016 

sl
```

First run:

```
Packages added until Mon Nov 14 08:24:17 BRT 2016 

Name
acpi-support-b
apt-listchange
aptitude-commo
aptitude-doc-e
bash-completio
ca-certificate
console-setup-

[...]
```

What could be causing this?

***Note**: I am running this script on a 64-bit Debian Jessie OS, and accessing this machine through SSH.*

Comment: Use `dpkg --get-selections|cut -f1`

Comment: @IporSircer what would this command do?

Comment: man dpkg: `--get-selections [package-name-pattern...]
              Get list of package selections, and write it to stdout.  Without
              a  pattern,  non-installed  packages (i.e. those which have been
              previously purged) will not be shown.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the info page for `date`:

> Invoking ‘date’ with no FORMAT argument is equivalent to invoking
>   it with a default format that depends on the ‘LC_TIME’ locale
>   category.

**Examples**

```
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 date
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8 date
```

*Sample Output*

```
Mon Nov 14 20:27:59 +07 2016
Пн ноя 14 20:28:04 +07 2016
```

So the behavior you described is due to your locale settings, namely the `LC_TIME` environment variable. Adjust it somewhere before running the script (on the target machine!), e.g.:

```
export LC_TIME=C
```

The other issues are most likely due to the locale settings as well. So adjust the rest of the locale environment variables in similar manner. `LANG` and `LC_NUMERIC` variables are particularly important. Check out the info page: `info bash LANG`.